# Displaying Category Name and Channel Entry Data with Query Module

Tags: query, mysql, sql, query-module

I have a SQL query set-up to display a list of entries based on the category ID found in the third segment, but I'm having a hell of a time trying to display the category name that goes along with it. This is what I have that's currently working:

```
SELECT
    cd.field_id_19 AS song_number,
    cd.field_id_20 AS song_title,
    cd.field_id_21 AS song_artist
FROM exp_channel_data cd
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts cp
ON cd.entry_id = cp.entry_id
WHERE cp.cat_id = {segment_3_category_id}
```

I know I have to add a JOIN with the exp_categories table in order for the exp_category_posts.cat_id to retrieve cat_name, but have not been successful in working it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to get the `cat_name` of the category on `segment_3` or of all categories of every entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin will give you all of that functionality that you can pass into a channel entries tag. http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat

Example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" category="{segment_3_category_id}"}
      {count} of {total_results} of the entries associated with that cat.

      {segment_3_category_name}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot. Thanks for pointing out the easiest of solutions there!

Comment: No problem this is a standard in all my EE installs. It is a great plugin and makes life easy.